# Heroku Push rejected, failed to compile ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net, heroku, asp.net-core-1.0

I exactly followed this link http://codersblock.com/blog/how-to-run-net-on-heroku/

to deploy the application on heroku but I am getting an error

Push rejected, failed to compile ASP.NET Core app.

when I execute git push heroku master.

If any body knows about the issue, it will be great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Share your error logs

Comment: Hi Mehta,
please see the error log detail:

-----> ASP.NET Core app detected
Stack heroku-16 not supported
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile ASP.NET Core app.
 !     Push failed

Thanks.

Comment: after searching on google I want to ask, did you set the buildpack?

Comment: heroku stack:set cedar-14      then   git push heroku master

Answer (score 1):

**what is heroku-16?**

there are different types of distros(`stacks`) which contains your app:

- heroku-16
- cedar-14   (supports dotNet-core.)

thats why we will switch to cedar-14

**how to fix:**

1- install  *heroku cli*. (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)

2- open cmd. type:

```
cd to/project/Root 

heroku stack:set cedar-14
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Dockerfile to generate a Docker image runnable on Heroku.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet <YOUR_API_NAME>.dll
```

Then you can publish it to Heroku either directly using these Docker commands:

```
docker build -t aspnetapp <YOUR_API_NAME>
docker login --username=$HEROKU_USERNAME --password=$HEROKU_API_KEY registry.heroku.com
docker tag aspnetapp registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME/web
docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME/web
```

In order these commands:

1. Create a Docker image and builds a release of your project in it
2. Connect to Heroku's docker registry using your credentials
3. Creates a new tag for your image
4. Publishes your image to your Heroku app

However, if your machine does not support Docker, you can also use CircleCI to run these commands. More details here: 
 https://www.codingnagger.com/2018/02/21/continuous-delivery/

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar problem and spent almost the whole day debugging it.

My issue, I was using *Microsoft.Net.Compilers* and I'd to remove that

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" Version="4.2.0">
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

and add

```
  <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
```

To .csproj (My case I was using clean architecture so I was doing these modifications in **Domain layer**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Note, I also have upgraded some of the packages it was complaining about been downgraded.